# <FbGraph::Exception: Unparsable Response: > fb_graph - rails 3.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api

I get this error only in production environment:

```
FbGraph::Exception: Unparsable Response:
```

when I call to feed!:

```
@fb_user ||= FbGraph::User.me(self.fb_token)
@fb_user.feed!(
      :message => "bla bla bla",
      :name => "site name",
      :link => page_in_my_site_url
    )
```

When I pass cucumber test, this works succesfully.

I use in production nginx and unicorn server, with ruby 1.9.3(rvm), rails 3.1.3, and fb_graph 2.4.4

Can anybody help me, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the response text that is not able to be parsed?

Comment: I just hit the same problem. If I find the s9olution I'll let you know

Comment: I don't know the response text, in fact, this is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just run into the same problem after updating my gems (as per comment on your question).
After looking at the github location for the gem and I noticed it had been updated recently and I think this update has introduced t6his problem.

I set my Gemfile definition to gem `'fb_graph', '~> 1.8.4'` and this resolved the issue for me.

**UPDATE**

I have just opened a ticket and if I find time I'll see if I can track down the problem in the source code of the gem (If there is one).

Comment: I had fb_graph 2.4.6 in my server and I had 2.4.4 in my local computer. Now, with fb_graph 2.4.4, I can see the response message. Thanks!